# Get Date from Timestamp using Regex

Tags: javascript, string, datetime

I am new to regex and want to take a timestamp and "extract" the date from it using Javascript's .replace function.

Timestamp:

```
2020-01-15T16:00-07:00[UTC]
```

Expected Result:

```
2020-01-15
```

What would be the regex I would use to get that result?

Comment: SO is here to help you with code you've written, not write it for you. You might want to match all characters from the "T" to the end of the string and replace them with an empty string.

Comment: does this answer you question? https://medium.com/coding-in-simple-english/how-to-parse-a-date-using-a-regular-expression-in-javascript-f4e5b1d02935

Comment: Why no just use .substr(0, 10)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/jX5Pt4/1 (I really recommend that website!)

This regex is fairly simple:

```
([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})
```

It will capture your date as "1st capture group" (the parenthesis)

EDIT:

Yeah, it's better to match the rest of the data and replace it with empty string.

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/jX5Pt4/2

REGEX:

```
T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(\[UTC\])?
```

This will match the rest of the string taking UTC as optional (last question mark)

Comment: Perfect, yea the syntax for Regex gets a bit confusing for me at times, but this definitely helps! Thanks for the website as well!

Comment: `date.replace(/T.*$/,'')` is a lot simpler.

Comment: @RobG Yup, but can match other stuff as well, till the end of line :)

Comment: Yes, that's the point. Your regex will fail with a timestamp like "2020-01-15T16:00+07:00[UTC]", or any other minor variation in format. Given the OP only cares about the date, I don't see any need to be specific about other parts of the timestamp. I'd use *substring* as it's a more efficient solution.